# Unknown javadoc format for FXMLLoader

Tags: java, exception, model, javafx-2, fxmlloader

I am trying to implement a basic Javafx application, FXMLLoader.load can't seem to load in my Test.fxml file, which I made using Scene Builder 2.0

```
public class Main extends Application {
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Test.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

  }
}
```

And it gives the following exception:

Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Unknown javadoc format for FXML {key=Ljavafx/fxml/FXML;} [in FXML.class [in javafx.fxml [in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar]]]]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavadocContents.getTypeDoc(JavadocContents.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryType.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)

My Test.fxml file is in the same directory as my Main.java.

Comment: It gives this exception when you try to run it, or during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was pathing since creating a new project put my Main.java into an application package so it worked liek this :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Test.fxml"));
```